# Help with an ID on this road bike

Tags: identify-this-bike, vintage, used-bike

I found this road bike on Kijiji. The vintage road bike market in my area is terrible, so $125 for something in this condition is the cheapest I've seen.

Is this bike any good? I am looking for something to fix up and restore.

[image]
[imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqYxO.jpg)

Comment: It's a decent (though not valuable) bike ca 1980.  Looks a lot like my old Nishiki of that vintage.

Comment: Its a 40 year old bike - there will be problems.  You will have to spot them, and then possibly bargain the seller down.   Or look at the shipping cost of buying a bike elsewhere.